# Does Siquieros' Echo of a Scream resemble a known news photo from the Second Sino-Japanese War?

Tags: art, photography, painting, sino-japanese-war

[image: Echo of a Scream]

This is *Echo of a Scream*, a 1937 painting by Mexican artist [David Alfaro Siqueiros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Alfaro_Siqueiros). According to the book *[History of Modern Art](https://www.google.com/books/edition/History_of_modern_art/bFBIAQAAIAAJ)* this painting was based on "an actual news photograph of a child in the aftermath of a bombing in [the contemporaneous Sino-Japanese war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Sino-Japanese_War)". I can't find any further documentation of this. Does such a photo exist?

Comment: There is a brief reference in Japanese Wiki about this, but further googling did not produce anything that links this painting with the bombing in Sino-Japanese war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Bloody Saturday]

Answering my own question here, I think I found it. [Known as "Bloody Saturday"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody_Saturday_(photograph)), this photo was very widely seen around the world in September to October, 1937. The angle is different but otherwise I would say the resemblance is clear enough that it seems likely to be Siquieros' inspiration. The photo was taken at the Shanghai Railway Station. The Wikipedia article provides quite a bit of further context.

Comment: But you know what, he was a die hard communist ( or more a Stalinist ) and according to Wiki(English) link [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Alfaro_Siqueiros ] "**The Siqueiros Experimental Workshop only lasted for a little over a year until Siqueiros went to fight in the Spanish Civil War in April 1937**", so that it is very likely that the picture was drawn to show the misery of Spanish war rather than Sino-Japanese war. (Also note in Sino-Japanese war, main enemy to JIA  was Kuotaming, not Chinese communists back then)

Comment: Yes. It would seem that the photo was merely a visual point of reference.